# Datatables Server side processing very slow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using [Datatables server side processing](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) using PHP, Jquery, Ajax and my database in SQL Server.

The data is displayed correctly in a table But the features like pagination and search are very slow. Everytime I type in seach box or i change pagination to next page I am waiting more than 40 seconds although i am not dealing with large data.

Here is my index page

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=utf-8" />
  <title> Datatables using PHP Ajax Jquery </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable({
            "columns": [
                {"data": "Country"},
                {"data": "Customer"},
                {"data": "Address"},
                {"data": "Contact"},
                {"data": "Price"},
                {"data": "Qty"}
            ],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: 'fetch.php',
                type: 'POST'
            }
        });
} );
</script>
```

and here is my fetch.php where is the Ajax call

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!empty($_POST) ) {

$ser="****";
$db="****";
$user="****"; 
$pass="****";
$MyTable="****";

$dbDB = new PDO("odbc:Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;Server=****;Database=****", $user, $pass);


    function getData($sql){
        global $dbDB ;
        global $MyTable ;
        $result = $dbDB->query($sql);
        $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $data[] = $row ; }
        return $data; }

    $draw = $_POST["draw"];
    $orderByColumnIndex  = $_POST['order'][0]['column'];
    $orderBy = $_POST['columns'][$orderByColumnIndex]['data'];
    $orderType = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; 
    $start  = $_POST["start"];
    $length = $_POST['length'];

    $recordsTotal = count(getData("SELECT * FROM ".$MyTable));

    if(!empty($_POST['search']['value'])){

        for($i=0 ; $i<count($_POST['columns']);$i++){
            $column = $_POST['columns'][$i]['data'];
            $where[]="$column like '%".$_POST['search']['value']."%'";
        }
        $where = "WHERE ".implode(" OR " , $where);

        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s %s", $MyTable , $where);
        $recordsFiltered = count(getData($sql));

         $sql = sprintf("SELECT Country,Customer,Address,Contact,Price,Qty FROM %s %s ORDER BY %s %s OFFSET %d ROWS FETCH NEXT %d ROWS ONLY", $MyTable , $where ,$orderBy, $orderType ,$start,$length);
         $data = getData($sql);
    }

    else {
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT Country,Customer,Address,Contact,Price,Qty FROM %s ORDER BY %s %s OFFSET %d ROWS FETCH NEXT %d ROWS ONLY", $MyTable ,$orderBy, $orderType ,$start,$length);
        $data = getData($sql);
        $recordsFiltered = $recordsTotal;
    }

        $response = array(
        "draw" => intval($draw),
        "recordsTotal" => $recordsTotal,
        "recordsFiltered" => $recordsFiltered,
        "data" => $data
    );

    echo json_encode($response);

} 

else {
    echo "NO POST Query from DataTable";
}

?>
```

I don't understand why the search and pagination are very slow when i use server side processing. I checked some options in datatables documentation but it didn't speed up the loading time.

any ideas please where could be the issue ? Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to benchmark your SQL execution times using `microtime(true)` or else this question is way too broad and practically unanswerable.

Comment: Do you run it on your local server? How much time does it take to wait for other requests?

Comment: An `EXPLAIN` on the queries wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Another Unnecessary step `$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and then a loop to move this exact array to another called `$data` Just do `$data= $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and get rid of the unnecessary loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, i removed the unnecessary part but the search and pagination are still slow

Answer (score 0):

It's just guessing (i.e. there might be some weird javascript library that's nuking your loading times), but it probably has to do with these lines:

```
$recordsTotal = count(getData("SELECT * FROM ".$MyTable));

$recordsFiltered = count(getData($sql));
```

You're selecting everything from the database and then proceed to count those rows with PHP. A database can do this infinitely faster with the [COUNT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_count.asp) function.

Also, the optimum path for your code involves 2 database queries. The other requires 3 queries, from which 2 are incredibly heavy on performance.

Comment: I changed it  to  $recordsTotal  = $dbDB->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$MyTable)->fetchColumn(); but the search and pagination are still slow

Comment: Then there's probably something else. Check the "network" or "performance" tab of your developer tools in the browser when you try to search and paginate. Maybe that can shed some light in what is going on.